# Does being worthy negate the weight of Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

We know that [Thor's hammer has a weight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/how-much-would-thors-hammer-mjolnir-weigh), and that the weight is irrelevant to the ability to wield Mjolnir - but rather how worthy the wielder is.

However, most of the people who have canonically wielded Mjolnir have been quite strong - Captain America, Beta Ray Bill - even a regular human paramedics would have some strength as part of the job. For example, if an replica of Mjolnir were made of regular steel, Captain America would easily be able to wield the estimated 30-50kg hammer.

However, **has there been a situation where someone was deemed "worthy" to wield the hammer, but would not have normally had the strength an equivalent non-enchanted hammer, but was still able to lift it?** For example, Thor is immobilised, a small child of pure heart is nearby and is able to lift the hammer to free him?

Similarly, if one is worthy of wielding Mjolnir, do they gain the equivalent strength to lift anything of comparable weight or just the hammer?

---

Edit for clarification:

If we assume Mjolnir when stripped of all enchantments has a fixed weight, and that weight for arguments sake is 100kg, it would stand to reason that the only people capable of wielding it would be super strong. This question is about how the enchantments alter how wieldable it is. Lets assume a small child was deemed worth by Odin of wielding Mjolnir, but this child can lift at most 20kg. The enchantment is useless, as *even though the child may wield Mjolnir, it effectively cannot because its not strong enough to lift the unenchanted weight.*

Comment: That thing is denser than a Neutron Star. So, it's natural non-enchanted weight should be more than that of Earth. Neither Captain American, nor Thor would be able to life it the magic wouldn't nullify its real weight.

Comment: @SS - It's not denser than a neutron star; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54581/20774

Comment: wasn't there a whole episode of the big bang theory devoted to this question?

Comment: @StevenWood referencing a Big Bang theory is right up there with referencing an XKCD.

Comment: Wielding isn't just about lifting the weight. Suppose the hammer were made *lighter* so a child could lift ... then they wouldn't have the strength to *hit* anything very hard with it; it would be like a nerf gun.

Comment: Imagine if you were worthy but you couldn’t lift it because it was too heavy...

Answer (score 21):

One example that springs to mind is the best-named hero in the Marvel Universe: [Throg, Frog of Thunder](http://marvel.wikia.com/Simon_Walterson_(Earth-616)), a member of the Pet Avengers<sup>1</sup>. Throg was a human football (American football) player who was transformed into a frog by a Gypsy curse. And not a human-sized frog either: a normal-sized frog. Here's a picture of him next to a regular-sized goat, for reference<sup>2</sup>:

[image: The forging of Frogjolnir]

Initially, Throg (Who was called Puddleglup at the time) had no superhuman<sup>3</sup> powers; he was just a dude who seriously pissed off a gypsy and got turned into a frog. As one does.

In his first appearance, Puddleglup was deemed worthy of the Power of Thor. However, he never attempted to actually lift Mjolnir in its entirety. Instead he lifted a shard that broke off when Thor was fighting, and that shar transformed him into Throg.

However, in the same issue Thor had been turned into a frog by Loki, and he was able to lift Mjolnir with only minor difficulties:

[image: Thor in a frog's form lifts Mjolnir]

SInce we had no indication that Thor in his frog-form was any more physically powerful than a normal frog, we can speculate that Throg would also be able to lift it. While I hesitate to say that he could actually *wield* a full-sized Mjolnir, even lifting it is not something you'd expect from a regular Earth-frog.

A better example would be [the duplicate Jake Olson](http://marvel.wikia.com/Jake_Olson_(Duplicate)_(Earth-616)), who was essentially a golem created by Loki and inhabited by the revived spirit of Jake Olson. This duplicate had a complicated relationship with Thor (They shared the same body for a time), but he was otherwise a perfectly ordinary human - . In "Thor Vol. 2 #67", Jake picked up the hammer and used it against an increasingly-unstable Thor.

To answer your second question, when wielding the Frog-sized Frogjolnir, Throg possesses all the powers of Thor, including super-strength proportional to his size. That is to say, he's incredibly strong for a frog, but not as strong as Thor.

I suspect the same would be true for Jake Olson, although I can't say for sure.

Clearly when Odin said "Whomsoever is deemed worthy", he damned well meant it.

And just because I literally cannot get enough of this character, he's a picture of Throg in full Frog of Thunder regalia:

[image: Throg, Frog of Thunder]

---

<sup>1</sup> Because the 80's were a wonderful time to be alive
<sup>2</sup> The hammer pictured is **not** Mjolnir; it's Frogjolnir<sup>4</sup>, a miniature version crafted from a sliver of Mjolnir.
<sup>3</sup> Super-amphibian?
<sup>4</sup> Because the writers had a theme going, and damned if they were going to break it

Comment: I can't believe there was actually an answer to this crazy-ass question.

Comment: Wow...  Yeah...  +1 for that bizarre find!  Hahaha

Comment: @Chris I can easily believe an answer existed - in fact the OP's suggestion of a small child picking it up for a temporarily disabled Thor seemed pretty plausible. I'm frankly surprised that the answer was a *frog*

Comment: This is a great answer (Odin's knows I love Throg), but considering he's lifting Frogjolnir, I'll hold off to see if there is an example of someone lifting Mjolnir.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr You're actually somewhat right; that second picture is actually *Thor*, just transformed into a frog. It is canon, however, that Throg was able to lift Mjolnir. I'm going to see if I can find an actual screen of the panel

Comment: Oh whoops, I misread the footnotes. Also, thanks for adding the picture of Throg in full costume. *You are a frog among men.*

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Closer reading has revealed that I was somewhat mistaken; Throg never lifted Mjolnir in its entirety, only the sliver that later became Frogjolnir. However, since Thor in a frog's body was able to lift the hammer, we can speculate that Throg probably could as well - there's no indication that frog!Thor was any physically stronger than a normal frog. However, I found a (less hilarious) example that also serves. Editing now

Comment: I'm looking forward to asking "If Thor were turned into a frog, could he still lift Mjolnir?" just so it can be marked as a dupe.

Comment: `'Puddleglup'`?  I think somebody must have read The Magician's Nephew...

Answer (score 2):

People make a lot of the "forged from a dying star" line, but frankly it's NEVER shown to be that heavy or powerful.  It's almost always shown to be a hammer of normal weight (call it, a few dozen to a hundred pounds) that is WEIGHTED by magic, rather than a super-heavy object which is lightened by magic.  If that hammer, even when wielded by someone worthy, was as dense as a neutron star, it would crack the planet when he smashed the ground, not simply break a sidewalk.  And as many have pointed out, it would break any surface (including the crust of the Earth) it rested on.

To more specifically answer your question: I've never heard of anyone who was worthy being too weak to lift it, and those worthy of lifting it don't get super-strength toward any other objects, the enchantment on the hammer is simply lifted.  Both of these point to the idea that the hammer isn't actually very heavy on its own, and that it's the enchantment which makes it so.

So no, being worthy doesn't negate the weight of the hammer, being unworthy amplifies it.

Comment: I should point out that it's never (To my knowledge) said that Mjolnir was forged from a dying star. The typical line is that it was forged **in** a dying star, which has significantly different implications

Comment: @JasonBaker I'd never thought of that, but that is a very important distinction!  Nice catch.  :)

Comment: So the hammer is lets say about 80pounds/40kg/2.5pood, even then thats quite heavy for most people. Which raises the question, if someone is unable to lift an unenchanted hammer of the same size as Mjolnir, could they lift Mjolnir if deemed worthy?

Comment: According to Jason's answer it would seem so.

Comment: This answer has a lot of speculation about how the hammer works - its natural weight, and that it increases or decreases in weight.  There are other methods it could use to prevent (or assist) a potential wielder.  For example, instead of becoming heavier or lighter, it could simply use its propulsion technology to resist or assist its movement.  Furthermore, it's not necessarily "magic", because Thor basically paraphrased Aurthur C Clark when discussing Asguardian technology... It's so advanced that "some *call* it magic".

Comment: @Lakey That line is from the Thor film, but the question is tagged for both the comics and the movies.  In the comics, Asgard is sometimes shown to be advanced technology, but sometimes it's literally a magical realm, depending on the writer.

Comment: Ahh ok, well I cant argue with that.  They have a lot of random stuff in the comics, so I guess I don't know what is canon and what isn't

Comment: @Lakey: Neither do 90% of comic book writers.

Answer (score 2):

## Worthiness does not negate its normal weight.

In Age of Ultron, Thor and Vision have a brief conversation about Mjolnir.

> Vision: It's terribly well balanced.
>
> Thor: Well, if there's too much weight, you lose power on the swing.